# Compile Error while migrating from groovy to kotlin dsl

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, groovy, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am migrating certain Gradle project from the Groovy to the Kotlin DSL.
My module level build.gradle.kts are showed below.

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.sudoku"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.sudoku"
        minSdk = 29
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.3.2"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            exclude("/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}")
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0")
    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.1")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-*:2.6.0")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.5.2")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}
```

And my top level build.gradle.kts is like this.

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.0.2" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "8.0.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.7.20" apply false
}
```

Here's my settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "Sudoku"
include ':app'
```

Sync went well. However, while i was trying to build my app and install it on my phone using "run app" in Android Studio, failure occured.

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
```

like this and so on which didn't happen when my groovy time
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/De4Lt.png)

Tried Invalid Cache and Delete .gradle && .idea. None worked for me.
Much thanks!